# Terminal rename tab

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Is there a way to rename a tab in pantheon terminal? I looked in dconf-editor but did not see a setting for it to change the name. I tried right clicking on the tab and did not see it as an option.

Answer (score 2):

(0.4 loki) Pantheon tabs display the path (current working directory) and the last command (being) executed. You can change the directory or execute a command to change them but tabs cannot actually be named.